# representation of custom deformation on a meshgrid

Tags: differential-equations, visualization, mesh, finite-element-method

I am trying to represent 2D deformations on a rectangular grid. In Mathematica 10, there is a method to solve the elastic differential equations and then represent the deformation as presented here:

https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/compute-a-plane-strain-deformation.html

Now I only want to visualize a deformation I actually have an analytic functional form for, i.e. I do have the functions `u[x_,y_]` and `v[x_,y_]` which represent the deformation in the x and y directions, however I cannot get it working. I thought that the PDE solver `NDSolveValue` returns some `InterpolatingFunction` so I tried to use an `InterpolatingFunction` type of object for `u` and `v` (which, I know it sounds stupid), but even doing so, the `u["ElementMesh"]` returns `None` so I'm completely stuck in here. Any help would be appreciated!

Bonus question: is it possible to color the mesh according to the deformation (by defining some color scale, for instance)?

[image: A deformation field visualized with the finite element package]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to create your own `mesh` and you have to convert your `u` and `v` to mesh interpolations.  (In the example in the documentation, `NDSolveValue` does this itself in constructing `uif`, `vif`.)

Example:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}];

u = Function[{x, y}, x (y - 0.5)/25];
v = Function[{x, y}, -x^2/50];

uif = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, u @@@ mesh["Coordinates"]];
vif = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, v @@@ mesh["Coordinates"]];

ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uif, vif}][
 "Wireframe"["ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update 1* - Thanks to [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21) for the help with how to use `ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex` to process the deformed mesh.

Coloring by the norm of `{u, v}`, via post-processing:

```
nm = ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uif, vif}];

Show[
 Graphics[
  ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[nm, All, 
   VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ 
      Rescale[Norm[{u @@ #, v @@ #}] & /@ mesh["Coordinates"]])]],
 nm["Wireframe"]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The graphics consists of a single `Polygon` object inside a `GraphicsComplex`.  This is the easiest way to get a coloring that depends on position coordinates.)

*Update 2* - Various approaches to coloring.

For a function of the **coordinates**, use the following form for `VertexColors`:

```
colorscalar[x_, y_] := Norm[{u[x, y], v[x, y]}];
VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[colorscalar @@@ mesh["Coordinates"]])
```

For a function of a **point**, use the following form for `VertexColors`:

```
colorscalar[{x_, y_}] := Norm[{u[x, y], v[x, y]}];
VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[colorscalar /@ mesh["Coordinates"]])
```

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: Any comments on the coloring?...

Comment: Yes, basically the question is how to color the deformed mesh according to the deformation (larger deformations with warmer colors, smaller ones with colder colors, for example). I haven't used Directive so far, so I'm not even sure that this is possible. I'd like to do something like this: http://www.comsol.com/support/knowledgebase/1003/files/3123/kb_1003_plot_mesh_with_sol.png on the deformed mesh (and in 2D, of course). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice! Is there a way to keep the mesh as well?... Shall I combine the Directive of the meshgrid and the colored image?

Comment: `nm = ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uif, vif}]` will give you a new mesh. You could then use `Graphics[ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[nm, All, 
  VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ 
     Rescale[Norm[{u @@ #, v @@ #}] & /@ nm["Coordinates"]])]]` to make the conversion.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Botond You're welcome.  I'm thinking that the coordinates used for the coloring ought to be the original ones `mesh["Coordinates"]` instead of the deformed ones `nm["Coordinates"]`. It makes an imperceptible difference, but doesn't using `mesh` seem the correct way to you?

Comment: @MichaelE2, that is correct. mesh is the initial reference frame, and this becomes very important, especially when the displacement field is not homogeneous. Also, one last thing: it would be nice to actually color according to the strain rather than the displacement, i.e. specifying a scalar function ep[x_,y_] which is used only for the coloring. I guess that could be done somehow by substituting Norm[{u @@ #, v @@ #}] by ep, but I'm still struggeling with understanding the syntax...

Comment: @MichaelE2, yes, of course it should be the non deformed `mesh["Coordinates"]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I'm not sure about the difference between "function of the coordinates" and "function of a point", however the first one (function of the coordinates) works for me just as I expected!

Comment: @MichaelE2, I added some documentation of `ElementMeshToGraphoicsComplex` and a variation of this example. It's going to be available in a future version. Thanks!

Comment: @Botond The function of a point basically has a single argument of the from an ordered pair `{x, y}`; the function of the coordinates is a function of two arguments, each a number, `x` and `y`.  Look closely at the form of the definition of `colorscalar` in the two examples.  The first matches the `ep` in your comment; the second is basically like the function in my example.  That's why I showed both.  The curious can also ponder why `Apply` (`@@@`) and `Map` (`/@`) are the appropriate operations for each respective case.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks a lot, I see it now. Also, thanks for all your help guys, I've been struggling with this for days!

Comment: @user21 You're welcome and thanks, too!  I appreciate the work you've put into the documentation.  It's very helpful.

Comment: I managed to make some really nice plots with this method. One thing I couldn't get working is to add a simple colorbar to the right of the plot corresponding to the color scale of the plot. The standard PlotLegend doesn't seem to work... Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `Legended` and `BarLegend` will do it. I'm in a field where legending is unimportant, unlike many others, judging by the many questions on this site about issues with legends.  You might search the site, if my suggestion doesn't work.