# How to use RadialGradientFilling in Mathematica 11.1

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to create a disk with a radial gradient.  I found the built in function "RadialGradientFilling" which should do the trick but, alas, I am using an older version of Mathematica where it is not supported.  Is there any work around to be able to do something along the lines of

```
Graphics[{RadialGradientFilling[{Red, Blue}], Disk[]}]
```

in Mathematica 11.1?  I know its possible to make a grid of points with some color distribution but I really need it to be applied to a Disk graphic.  Any thoughts?

The actual code I'm working on can be found down below.  I'm trying to give the gradient color to the yellow Graphic

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{npoints = 2000, munit = 10^11, plotsize = 10, 
   sec2rad = Pi/(180. 3600.), sxy}, 
  imagePos[sourcexy_, mass_, distlens_] := 
   Module[{g = 6.6726*10^-11(*m^3/(kg s^2)*), c = 2.99792458*10^8(*m/
     s*), msun = 1.989*10^30(*kg*), parsec = 3.0856*10^16(*m*), 
     ly = 3.26(*parsec*), ds, dl, b, bx, by, u, t1, t2, image1, 
     image2, images},
    b = Sqrt[Total[sourcexy^2]];
    If[b > 10^-10,
     ds = 1 parsec 10^9;
     dl = (distlens parsec 10^9)/ly;
     u = 4 msun Abs[ds - dl]/(ds dl) (g  mass)/c^2;
     t1 = (1 + Sqrt[1 + (4 u)/b^2])/2;
     t2 = (1 - Sqrt[1 + (4 u)/b^2])/2,
     t1 = 0;
     t2 = 0];
    image1 = t1 sourcexy;
    image2 = t2 sourcexy;
    images = Join[List[image1], List[image2]];
    Return[images]];
  source[center_, r_, npoints_] := Module[{p, x, y, points},
    p = Table[(2 Pi)/npoints i, {i, 0, npoints}];
    x = List[center[[1]] + List[r Cos[p]]];
    y = List[center[[2]] + List[r Sin[p]]];
    points = MapThread[List, Flatten[List[x, y], 2]];
    Return[points]];
  If[Sqrt[sourcexy[[1]]^2 + sourcexy[[2]]^2] > 10^-4, sxy = sourcexy, 
   sxy = {0, 0}];
   If[Sqrt[sxy[[1]]^2 + sxy[[2]]^2] > r,
   Graphics[
    {{Yellow, 
      Polygon[Part[
        Flatten[1/
          sec2rad (imagePos[#, munit mass, dl] & /@ 
            source[sec2rad sxy, sec2rad r, npoints]), 1], 
        Table[i, {i, 1, 2 npoints - 1, 2}]]]}, {Yellow, 
      Polygon[Part[
        Flatten[1/
          sec2rad (imagePos[#, munit mass, dl] & /@ 
            source[sec2rad sxy, sec2rad r, npoints]), 1], 
        Table[i, {i, 2, 2 npoints, 2}]]]}, {Gray, 
      Disk[{0, 0}, plotsize/30]}, 
     Text["source-lens separation (arcsec):" PaddedForm[Sqrt[
        sxy[[1]]^2 + sxy[[2]]^2], {4, 2}], {-.06 plotsize, 
       5/6 plotsize + .5}]}, PlotRange -> plotsize, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
   Graphics[{{Yellow, 
      Polygon[Part[
        Flatten[1/
          sec2rad (imagePos[#, munit mass, dl] & /@ 
            source[sec2rad sxy, sec2rad r, npoints]), 1], 
        Table[i, {i, 1, 2 npoints - 1, 2}]]]}, {White, 
      Polygon[Part[
        Flatten[1/
          sec2rad (imagePos[#, munit mass, dl] & /@ 
            source[sec2rad sxy, sec2rad r, npoints]), 1], 
        Table[i, {i, 2, 2 npoints, 2}]]]}, {Gray, 
      Disk[{0, 0}, plotsize/30]}, 
     Text["source-lens separation (arcseconds):" PaddedForm[Sqrt[
        sxy[[1]]^2 + sxy[[2]]^2], {4, 2}], {-.06 plotsize, 
       5/6 plotsize + .5}]}, PlotRange -> plotsize, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> {400, 400}]]],
 {{sourcexy, {0, 0}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator},
 "distance to lens in \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(9\)]\) light \
years",
 {{dl, 1.5, ""}, 0.4, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 "radius of circular image in arcsec",
 {{r, 1, ""}, 0.1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 "mass of lens in \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(11\)]\) solar \
masses", 
 {{mass, 10, ""}, 0.1, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {sourcexy, dl, r, mass}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the remark about a "grid of points" disqualifies this approach, but here's way to apply a gradient to a `Disk[]`:

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.002];
Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[reg],
  MeshCells[reg, 2],
  VertexColors ->
   (Blend[{Red, Blue}, Norm[#]] & /@ MeshCoordinates[reg])
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

I'm not sure about the "yellow graphic" since the original post said and still says "disk", both of which are colored gray in the update.  Here's a **disk**:

```
gradDisk // ClearAll;
gradDisk[ctr_, rad_, cf_, 
   meshOpts : OptionsPattern@DiscretizeRegion] := 
  With[{reg = DiscretizeRegion[
      ConvexHullMesh[
       Table[ctr + rad {Cos[t], Sin[t]},
        {t, Most@Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, 120]}]],
      meshOpts
      ]},
   GraphicsComplex[
    MeshCoordinates[reg],
    MeshCells[reg, 2],
    VertexColors -> (cf /@
     (EuclideanDistance[ctr, #]/rad & /@ MeshCoordinates[reg]))
    ]
   ];

Graphics[{
  gradDisk[{0, 0}, 1, Blend[{Yellow, Blue}, #] &, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1],
  gradDisk[{1.2, 1.5}, 1, Blend[{Yellow, Blue}, #] &, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001],
  gradDisk[{2.5, 0}, 1.5, ColorData@"Rainbow"],
  gradDisk[{4, 1}, 1.5, ColorData@"Rainbow", MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: This definitely looks good!  I'm just trying to see how it can be applied to my specific scenario.  I updated the question with the actual code I am working on.  I'm trying to give the yellow graphic a gradient of some kind

Comment: @sorabella91 Do you want a `Disk[]` or a `Polygon[]` to have the gradient? How is a radial gradient defined for a polygon, by its circumcircle? Using `reg = DiscretizeRegion[Polygon[..]]` with `{ctr, rad} = List @@ Circumsphere@Polygon[..]` could be used in the above code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Yes I am trying to apply the gradient to the polygon graphic in the longer code.  I was just using the disk as an example

Comment: So the polygon graphic is actually a disk that becomes distorted by a lensing effect.  I imagined the gradient would distort with the image of the disk but perhaps that's too complicated...

Comment: @sorabella91 It's probably not too complicated — probably easy if the distortion is given as a function (formulas) from the disk to the distorted disk. But you need to ask for help on the problem you actually wanted solved, I think. — Here's an example of a distorted rectangle with a gradient: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69138/4999